# How does Google Now retrieve public transit information?

Tags: google-now

I just activated Google Now and turned on location access, and found that it showed cards about public transit that was due at the stop I was waiting at. Chennai city as of now doesn't contain live tracking by Google, though.

Are they tracking other nearby GPS devices? I would guess that is not possible since a GPS device is a passive one. Can someone shed some light on how this works?

Comment: Most of the public transit info given by google for chennai is wrong. They were updated last in 2011 I guess. Google began public transit for major cities like Chennai, Mumbai etc in mid 2010.

Comment: and the transit were provided by private agencies

Comment: It's a [new feature](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/06/07/google-now-has-an-alarm-that-can-wake-you-up-to-keep-you-from-missing-your-stop-on-public-transportation/). But Google Maps has had transit information for quite some time, and keeps adding more.

Comment: @sameer - Is that publicly available to be shared as APIs ?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions?hl=lv

Comment: And this is not a programming site. You better ask programming  related questions in Stackoverflow.

Comment: @sameer - please don't assume that my question lead to asking code stuff. In fact the javascript api link which you have shared is for the public transit. I was requesting you to share the piece of info which you meant by "and the transit were provided by private agencies". I wanted to have the data which was shared, just in case you got me wrong. No part of my question was related to asking "Please share me the code".

Comment: @AbhilashLR here is the list of agencies https://code.google.com/p/googletransitdatafeed/wiki/PublicFeeds

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/a/10625352/3275057